# Google Home send GET request and say response

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-home

There is an API available online that responds with a number (number of points) when you submit a GET request to a certain URL.

I'd like my Google Home to say this information when I ask it to. I have attempted to do this with DialogFlow but I'm not sure how I would go about doing it.

EDIT: I used the DialogFlow fulfillment webhook feature. DialogFlow sends a post request to my webserver and the server responds with "fulfillmentText" which is what the Google Home will say.

Comment: Please provide the code you tried to use.

Comment: @Mozzle It's not really code per say, more like you typing desired intent. As for the action, I did not know how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built-into Google Home that will get information out of the page at a URL.

You can write a program that will be triggered by the Assistant using [Actions on Google](http://developers.google.com/actions). This includes something that would run through [Dialogflow](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/), or it could run through the [Actions SDK](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/). Either way - you would do this by writing a program that would be called in a [webhook](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment) to fetch the data and return a message that would be read by the Assistant on your Home.